# jQuery variable handling

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a form where I want to change an input's type jQuery, and thanks to this wonderful website I've already found out that I need to clone and replace the input to change the type.
The problem I've run into is I added a variable and when I run the code it just doesn't work, it does work though when I use the ID of the input instead of the variable. Code is below.

These are the variables:

```
var productOne = $j("#ninja_forms_field_25");
var productOneDiv = $j("#ninja_forms_field_25_div_wrap");
```

This code doesn't work:

```
$j(".button1").click(function() {
        $j(productOneDiv).css("height", "37px");
        $j(productOne).clone().attr({
            "type": "text",
            "placeholder": "Product"
        }).insertAfter(productOne).prev().remove();
    });
```

This is the code that works:

```
$j(".button1").click(function() {
        $j("#ninja_forms_field_25_div_wrap").css("height", "37px");
        $j("#ninja_forms_field_25").clone().attr({
            "type": "text",
            "placeholder": "Product"
        }).insertAfter("#ninja_forms_field_25").prev().remove();
    });
```

I've searched for solutions and really couldn't find anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your variable declaration. There is no need to cast a string as a jQuery object.

Try:

```
var productOne = "#ninja_forms_field_25";
var productOneDiv = "#ninja_forms_field_25_div_wrap";
```

Comment: This works, but I hate re-instantiating jQuery objects when there's no need to.

Answer (score 1):

finally your problem with **$j**  you can use **$** or **jQuery** instead .. and your code will work fine

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/am1ejawq/3/)**

**Additional:**

while you use

```
var productOne = $("#ninja_forms_field_25");
```

you make it an object .. if you alert it you will get `[object Object]`

[simple demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/am1ejawq/)

> Basics: $(selector).action() or  jQuery(selector).action()

use it like

```
productOne.css() // directly .. no need to use it in $j(productOne)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. When you use `$j(productOneDiv).css` it's like writing `$j($j("#ninja_forms_field_25")).css`. productOneDiv is its own jQuery object.

Comment: This makes no difference at all. Code `$($($(window)))` and you will have a jQuery object with `length` of `1`.

Comment: I tried to edit, but am no longer able to. I just realized what the true issue was, while I still do see this as a problem, it's not THE problem. I'm explaining in my answer.

Comment: Agreed. I said that in the last comment I made. This is not THE problem.

Comment: @Vohuman you are totally right I will update my answer with right solution .. if I don't find a right answer I will delete my answer .. Sorry about that

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef Your answer helps performance wise, and I definitely agree that he should be doing what your answer said, but the issue is that he was still refering to the old productOne jQuery object when he actually needed to update it to the cloned element's jQuery object.

Comment: @BAM5 I updated my answer and it works fine in the demo above .. till now we not getting any response from OP .. I readed alot but if you find a good reference talking about the different between $j and $   just let me know .. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I figure I'll write out a bit of an answer here to fully explain.

What you want to do (change the type of an input) is fully possible in modern browsers; jQuery just forbids it because it won't work on older versions of IE and jQuery's mission is to be cross-browser compatible.

What you have is correct, but it will only work once, after which you replace the `#ninja_forms_field_25` DOM element and the `productOne` jQuery object will continue to refer to that replaced object internally. So in order to get it to work you just assign the new jQuery object to `productOne` like so

```
$j(".button1").click(function() {
        productOneDiv.css("height", "37px");
        productOne = productOne.clone().attr({
            "type": "text",
            "placeholder": "Product"
        }).insertAfter(productOne);
        productOne.prev().remove();
    });
```